# Python MySQL (import pymysql)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

If I use ***IDLE editor*** there is *no any error occurs*. but when I use ***sublime or VS code*** and for output I run my file (*python test.py*) in terminal or CMD it generate this error I try many commands to resolve but nothing changes like

```
pip install mysql

pip install pymysql

pip install mysql-connector
```

and watch many error videos but this error is not resolving. If someone know please help regard this.

On IDLE SHELL everything's works fine but in CMD these errors come. I also attached Screenshots for further information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdliO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gznv.png)

Error in CMD:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ubaid\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymysql
  File "C:\Users\Ubaid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import connections  # noqa: E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Ubaid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 7, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 55, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\selectors.py", line 12, in <module>
    import select
  File "C:\Users\Ubaid\Desktop\Python\select.py", line 2, in <module>
    mysql=pymysql.connect(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pymysql' has no attribute 'connect' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

[image]

Command Prompt Screen shot

[image]

IDLE ScreenShot

Comment: Looks like you are running 2 different files? test.py vs select.py

Comment: Rename `select.py`, it's clashing with a core python module

Comment: I have the same code on both files. test.py and select.py and also select.py is not giving me any output.

Comment: I also attached the s.s, I restart my system close everything and get the same issue. @User404

Comment: @snakecharmerb check my another pic